# Using the GDAL library, what would lng_var be and how to complete a polygon?

Tags: python

Just need some help understanding some code.

What I am trying to do here is create a Shapefile and not sure if I am doing that correctly or not using the library gdal. It should be a shapefile that contains a grid of square polygons. Where each polygon cell is going to be 10 degrees by
10 degrees and the grid should cover the entire world. With the shapefile I am also trying to include a variable that contains a decimal
column called ‘LAND’ that will be populated with 0.0 for all rows/cells. Not sure I am doing this correctly, I had some filler code and now I am trying to figure out the parts that are needed to make this work. In the end it should look like this (18x36 grid):

[image]

```
form osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
import os
import random

# Specify that you want to work with a Shapefile
DriverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
# Not sure what this line does
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(DriverName)

# Name of shapefile to create
FileName = 'gride.shp'

# simple check to see if that file already exists in the system, if so delete it
if os.path.exists(FileName):
  driver.DeleteDataSource(FileName)

# Now create an Empty shapefile Data source
shapeData = driver.CreateDataSource(FileName)


fieldName = 'LAND'


lng_min = -180
lng_max = 180
step = 10

lat_min = -90
lat_max = 90


# lng_var = ??
# lat_var = ??

for lng_var in range(lng_min, lng_max, step):
    ring = org.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
    ring.AddPoint(lng_var, lat_var)
    ring.AddPoint(lng_var + step, lat_var)
    ring.AddPoint(lng_var + step, lat_var + step)
    ring.AddPoint()
    ring.AddPoint()
    poly = org.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
    poly.AddGeometry(ring)

    for lat_var in range(lat_min, lat_max, step):
        ring = org.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
        ring.AddPoint(lng_var, lat_var)
        ring.AddPoint(lng_var + step, lat_var)
        ring.AddPoint(lng_var + step, lat_var + step)
        ring.AddPoint()
        ring.AddPoint()
        poly = org.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
        poly.AddGeometry(ring)
```

I haven't found a way to integrate my fieldName = 'LAND' yet. Where that should contain the decimal column called ‘LAND’, populated with 0.0 for all rows/cells.

I want to after this is done be able to open it on QGIS.

Not sure how to complete the polygon that is where there is two AddPoint()'s and also not sure what lng_var will be, or the lat_var when I add the inner loop.

Comment: This looks like homework. If I were you, I would make a raster with random values in each cell, then polygonize it and set all the cell values to zero and rename that field "Land". But you're on a different and fine path.

Comment: @Jon a little lost on what you mean by this. Make a raster with random values in each cell? polygonize it? Set all cell values to zero? I just don't know how that would be done.

Comment: Try drawing out the five points on a piece of paper. First point, then "lng+step" (10 units right), then "lng+10, lat+10" (10 units right & 10 units up), and so on. Also, just a hint that your lat loop should probably come immediately under your lng loop and only make one set of five points.

Comment: @phloem why 5 points? To be honest I don't understand the reason to have the variable LAND why do we need a decimal column and what does it mean to be populated with 0.0 for all rows/cells? I am a little lost here on that.

Comment: You meant to tag @phloem.

Comment: @phloem I think I see what you mean, start from say - top left then go right, then go from that part go down, then from that point go left, then from that point go up. I understand that longitude is what will be shifting right and left and that latitude is what will be shifting up and down. So doesn't latitude act as rows and longitude act as cols? or do I have that backwards?

Comment: @Jon corrected!

Comment: So in thinking of outer loops and inner loops, is this the right idea. For every LATITUDE (ROW) we go across all the longitudes (COLS)? and that's how the grid gets populated?

Comment: @Ki_ it depends how you set up your loops, but the way you have it now, you'll be going from min_lng -> max_lng and min_lat -> max_lat, so that means bottom left to top right. And, you'll finish everything in the inner loop (lat), before moving onto the next outer loop (lng), so you'll make one column at a time, then move one more to the right. Also, it doesn't REALLY matter, but your points in each rectangle will start and end in the bottom left going counter-clockwise. Finally, you might find it easier, rather than making geometries, just print out the lat/lngs to see what's going on.

Comment: @phloem so would the LAT vary from top to bottom (N to S) and then LONG vary from left to right (W to E)?

Comment: @phloem and LAT ranges from -90N to +90S and LONG ranges rom -180W to +180E?

Comment: Well, for lat, -90 is the south pole and +90 is the north pole.

Comment: @phloem but for W to E that's -180W to +180E?